# Is the minimal modulus of continuity of a $C^k$ function also $C^k$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Define the minimal modulus of continuity of $f$, $\omega(f): \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ by

$$\omega(f)(\delta) := \inf \{\varepsilon > 0 \, \big | \, |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon \text{ for all }  x, y \in [0, 1] \text{ with } |x - y| < \delta\}.$$

**Question:** For $f$ a $C^k$ function, is $\omega(f)$ a $C^k$ function?

Here $C^k$ denotes the set of $k$ times differentiable functions.

Comment: I will pog you :)

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation and generosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\De\Delta\newcommand\om\omega$No. E.g., if $f(x)=\cos\pi x$, then
$$\om(f)(\de)=2\sin\Big(\frac\pi2\,\min(\de,1)\Big). $$
So, $f\in C^2$ but $\om(f)\notin C^2$.

A simpler example is $f(x)=x$. Then $\om(f)(\de)=\min(\de,1)$. So, $f\in C^1$ but $\om(f)\notin C^1$.

---

If the domain of $\om$ is restricted to $[0,1]$, there still is a counterexample. Indeed, let the function $f$ be such that for $x\in[0,1]$
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    x(1-x)(2-x)&\text{ if }x\le\frac2{10},\\
    \tfrac1{15}\,(x-2)&\text{ if }x\ge\frac2{10}.  
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
Here is the graph of $f$:

[image]

For the function $\om:=\om(f)$, we shall show that (i) $\om$ is constant in a right neighborhood of the point $\De:=\frac1{5\sqrt3}$ and hence the right second derivative of $\om$ at $\De$ is $0$, whereas the left second derivative of $\om$ at $\De$ is $<0$. So, $\om\notin C^2$.

Moreover, $\om(\De)$ is  strictly less than the largest value of $\om$.

Note that the continuous function $f$ is smooth everywhere on $[0,1]$ except at the point $\frac2{10}$.
However, we shall show that we can change $f$ in a neighborhood of $\frac2{10}$ to make the resulting function however smooth, without changing the values of $\om(\de)$ for $\de$ near $\De$ at all.

Thus, the modulus of continuity of the resulting smooth function will not be in $C^2$.

(Even though details of calculations will be provided below, one might say that the stated  properties of the function $f$ are almost obvious from the picture, except perhaps for the specific value of $\De$. Our visual apparatus is a powerful computer!)

---

Details of the corresponding calculations are shown below. These calculations -- for the piecewise-polynomial function $f$, with the degrees of the polynomials $\le3$, are quite elementary, but very nasty, as a large number of cases have to be considered. Therefore, these calculations are done with Mathematica:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course there will be a kink once the $\delta$ exceeds the functions’ max deviation. I wonder if it is as smooth as $f$ on its natural domain $(0, \sup f - \inf f]$ though, like @ChristianRemling suggests.

Comment: The first of these two examples can be modified for the domain $[0,1]$. I will write it up.

Comment: I have completed the details for the counterexample for the domain $[0,1]$.

Comment: Extremely impressive! I really like this quote: “Even though details of calculations will be provided below, one might say that the stated properties of the function $f$ are almost obvious from the picture, except perhaps for the specific value of $\Delta$. Our visual apparatus is a powerful computer!”

Comment: Humans are indeed pretty strong visually…

Comment: @NateRiver : Thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : I am not sure what you mean by "a boundary problem". In the main example in this answer, the effect is caused by something happening in an interior. Also, an example with the (horizontally rescaled) $\cos$ was already given in the beginning of the answer -- but then the effect was due to something happening indeed at a **boundary** point of the range of values of $\omega_f$. The main example in the answer fixes this non-desired only-at-the-boundary thing.

Comment: @Iosif Pinellis Yes, you are right. I will remove the comment.